# Is email post notify visitor on new media upload possible?

Tags: media, notifications

Is there a plugin or snippet that would:

1. Add an email input form to each post
2. Send a predefined message when new media (or attachments) has been uploaded for that post only

The requested functionality here is different from other plugins I am aware of because it targets only the end user and only on new media upload (as compared to comments).

Any insight at all would be helpful!

Comment: I am not sure about only media uploads - but there are many notification plugins that will notify users when post is updated. and if you click the "update post" button when new attachment is added - so It will notify them. as for upload via the media upload - I am sure that these plugins can be very easily be adapted to that (just add another trigger action on media save)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for the email input form, you can use any plugin for Custom Fields ( I use [Advanced Custom Fields](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) or [Custom Content Type Manager](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-content-type-manager/) ) or add you own meta box ( [tutorial](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) ).

And for sending an email to the address inserted as a custom field, use the following code.
The custom field is named **email_warn**.

The filter `wp_mail_content_type` enables html content for emails.
And `add_attachment` will fire at each upload, pull the parent ID and send an email if the custom field is defined and is a valid email

```
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'wpse_20324_mail_html' );
add_filter( 'add_attachment', 'wpse_20324_post_upload' );

function wpse_20324_mail_html()
{
    return "text/html";
}

function wpse_20324_post_upload( $attachment_ID )
{
    $uploaded = get_post( $attachment_ID );
    $email = get_post_meta( $uploaded->post_parent, 'email_warn', true );

    if( isset( $email ) && is_email( $email ) ) 
    {
        /**
         * The message will contain all post info about the uploaded file 
        */
        $vardump = print_r( $uploaded, true );
        $message = '<pre>' . $vardump . '</pre>';

        $headers = 'From: Test WPSE <test@test.com>' . "\r\n";

        wp_mail( $email, 'subject', $message, $headers );
    }
}
```